# What does the number meaning after the rdd

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

[image]

What does the meaning of the number in the bracket after rdd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number after RDD is its identifier:

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_151)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val rdd = sc.range(0, 42)
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Long] = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at range at <console>:24

scala> rdd.id
res0: Int = 1
```

It is used to track RDD across the session, for example for purposes like `caching`:

```
scala> rdd.cache
res1: rdd.type = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at range at <console>:24

scala> rdd.count
res2: Long = 42

scala> sc.getPersistentRDDs
res3: scala.collection.Map[Int,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_]] = Map(1 -> MapPartitionsRDD[1] at range at <console>:24)
```

This number is simple an [incremental integer](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1c9f95cb771ac78775a77edd1abfeb2d8ae2a124/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L2343) (`nextRddId` is just an `AtomicInteger`):

```
private[spark] def newRddId(): Int = nextRddId.getAndIncrement()
```

generated [when RDD is constructed](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/96ba217a06fbe1dad703447d7058cb7841653861/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L149-L150):

```
/** A unique ID for this RDD (within its SparkContext). */
val id: Int = sc.newRddId()
```

so if we followed:

```
scala> val pairs1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "foo")))
pairs1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, String)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[2] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> val pairs2 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "bar")))
pairs2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, String)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[3] at parallelize at <console>:24


scala> pairs1.id
res5: Int = 2

scala> pairs2.id
res6: Int = 3
```

you'll see 2 and 3, and if you execute

```
scala> pairs1.join(pairs2).foreach(_ => ())
```

you'd expect 4, which can confirmed by checking the UI:

[image]

We can also see that `join` creates a few new `RDDs` under the covers (`5` and `6`).