# Why does Spark increment the RDD ID by 2 instead of 1 when reading in text files?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I noticed something interesting when working with the `spark-shell` and I'm curious as to why this is happening. I load a text file into Spark using the basic syntax, and then I just simply repeat this command. The output of the REPL is below:

```
scala> val myreviews = sc.textFile("Reviews.csv")
myreviews: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = Reviews.csv MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:24

scala> val myreviews = sc.textFile("Reviews.csv")
myreviews: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = Reviews.csv MapPartitionsRDD[3] at textFile at <console>:24

scala> val myreviews = sc.textFile("Reviews.csv")
myreviews: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = Reviews.csv MapPartitionsRDD[5] at textFile at <console>:24

scala> val myreviews = sc.textFile("Reviews.csv")
myreviews: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = Reviews.csv MapPartitionsRDD[7] at textFile at <console>:24
```

I know that the `MapPartitionsRDD[X]` portion features `X` as the RDD identifier. However, based upon this [SO post on RDD identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277531/what-does-the-number-meaning-after-the-rdd), I'd expect that the identifier integer increments by one each time a new RDD is created. So why exactly is it incrementing by 2?

My guess is that loading a text file creates an intermediate RDD? Because clearly creating an RDD from `parallelize()` only increments the RDD counter by 1 (before it was 7):

```
scala> val arrayrdd = sc.parallelize(Array(3,4,5))
arrayrdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[8] at parallelize at <console>:24
```

Note: I don't believe the number has anything to do w/ partitions. If I call, I get that my RDD is partitioned into 9 partitions:

```
scala> myreviews.partitions.size
res2: Int = 9
```

Comment: Call getNumPartitions on the rdd and that should give you an idea

Comment: @sramalingam24 I get a value of 9 for partitions- how does this relate to the ID number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a single method call can create more than one intermediate `RDD`. It will be obvious if you check the debug string

```
sc.textFile("README.md").toDebugString
```

```
String =
(2) README.md MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:25 []
 |  README.md HadoopRDD[0] at textFile at <console>:25 []
```

As you see the lineage consist of two RDDs.

- The first one is a `HadoopRDD` which corresponds to [data import](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/86cc907448f0102ad0c185e87fcc897d0a32707f/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L842)

  ```
  hadoopFile(path, classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text],
    minPartitions)
  ```
- The second one is `MapPartitionsRDD` and corresponds to [the subsequent `map`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/86cc907448f0102ad0c185e87fcc897d0a32707f/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L843) which drops keys (offsets) and converts `Text` to `String`.

  ```
  .map(pair => pair._2.toString).setName(path)
  ```